# Distance from point to an infinitely long box

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Supose we have an infinitely long box and a point P, and we wish to calculate the shortest ditance from the surface of the box, and P.

Is there an alternative way, to calculating this, besides computing distances from each plane forming the box, and choosing the shortest one?

We may supose the box is axis aligned, as that is simply acomplished by rotations.

Answer (score 0):

If P is given by 3 coordinates and the box is defined by 2 boundaries in the X coordinate and 2 boundaries in the Y coordinate, then that is essentially the most efficient method. Note that the Z coordinate plays no role at all, so you might as well consider the problem of the distance from a point in the plane to the circumference of a rectangle.

If the rectangle (or the box) is not only aligned with the axes but also centered on the origin, so that the boundary values +a, -a, +b and -b are opposites, then the distance is the minimum of |x| - a and |y| - b.

All of this continues to be true if the point is inside the box (because we are interested in the distance to the *surface* of the box).